Wilson Loops for Lattice Gauge Theory on $\subset\mathbb{Z}^2$ over the gauge group $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\subset \mathbb{C}$
Is the potential complex valued?
I've simulated lattice gauge theory for a rectangular (finite) subset of $\mathbb{Z}^2$ over the gauge groups $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ (a.k.a. $\mathbb{Z}_n$) and $U(1)$, all being subsets of the unit circle in $\mathbb{C}$. I now want to get into some observables and Wilson loops seemed like a good choice. I found in [1] that the Wilson loop for a Euclidean Yang-Mills theory, with gauge group $G$, over a path $\gamma$ was defined as
$$W_\gamma = \text{Tr}\left(\mathcal{P}\exp\left(\int_\gamma \sum_{j=1}^n A_jdx_j\right)\right),$$
where $\mathcal{P}$ is the path-ordering operator. Luckily, for the discrete lattice gauge theories, it has the simpler definition
$$W_\gamma = \text{Tr}(U(e_1)U(e_2)\cdots U(e_m))$$
where $\gamma = (e_1, e_2, \dots, e_m)$ are the edges in the path (in the direction implied by the order of appearance), and $U(j)$ is the element of $G$ assigned to $j$ (in the corresponding direction).
In our case, $U(j) = e^{i\theta_j}$ for some $\theta_j$, so
$$W_\gamma=\exp\left(i\sum_{j=1}^m \theta_{e_j}\right)$$
that is, $W_\gamma$ is a complex number.
Furthermore, [1] the potential between a static quark and antiquark separated by distance R is given by the formula
$$V(R) = - \lim_{T\to\infty} \frac{1}{T}\log\langle W_{\gamma_{R,T}}\rangle$$
where $\gamma_{R,T}$ is a path of length $T$ and breadth $R$, and $\langle \bullet \rangle$ is the expectation with respect to a suitable Yang-Mills theory.
Since $W_\gamma \in\mathbb{C}$, then $V(R)\in\mathbb{C}$. However, I somewhere heard that $V$ was concave over $R$, which only makes sense if the image of $V$ is ordered (which isn't the case).
Am I wrong somewhere so far? Is $V(R)$ a complex number? is $V$ concave in some sense? If $V$ is complex valued, what does it mean for there to be a complex potential? Answering any subset of this questions or clarifying the subject in general is greatly appreciated.
Note: I'm a mathematical engineer mayor so I'm not super familiar with any of this at all.
References
[1] Chatterjee, S. (2018). Yang-Mills for probabilists. arXiv. Retrieved from https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.01950.

I think you are missing the reference you refer to as [1]?

@MartinC. Thanks! I've edited the question.

To answer your question, it is enough to know that the wilson loop is invariant under a change of orientation of the path, which amounts to taking the complex conjugate of all link variables inside the trace. This forces the Wilson loop to be a real valued object.
For more information, also on how the expression for the static potential is motivated you could consult chapter 7 of [1]
References
[1] Rothe, Heinz J. (2012). Lattice Gauge Theories, An Introduction (Fourth Edition). World Scientific Publishing Company. Retrieved from https://library.oapen.org/handle/20.500.12657/50492.

How is this consistent with the definition given in [1] which is the product of elements in the unit circle (without much restriction)?

I can not see where the inconsistency lies, can you point me to the specific page?

The Wilson loop is defined as as the trace of the product of elements  in $G$ (in this case (finite) subgroups of the unit circle). So the Wilson loop is a complex number. Is your claim that, whenever the system was sampled by the provided Boltzman distribution (p. 4 in the paper), it happens to be the case that the imaginary part of the elements being multiplied is $0$?
Note that even if the Wilson loop is real, the potential $V$ could still be complex: if $W = -1$ (which is very likely for $G=\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$), then $\log(-1)$ results in a complex value.

My claim is not regarding a sampling of the system, it is regarding the definition of the Wilson loop itself. The key here is that it is closed, i.e. that we connect the same point. To be more rigorous (this is even stated in your reference on page 7), the Wilson loop is the holonomy of a gauge connection along the closed path. This holonomy does not care about the orientation.

Regarding your second point, the definition of the static potential is made assuming a behaviour of the Wilson loop at large T that is exponential.
